# how to move from one tab to another tab by double click on table row

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/adminBody.js"></script>
<head>
<style >
.topMenu{
float:right;}
</style>
</head>
<div class="portlet-body">
<div class="tabbable tabbable-custom">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href = "#jobs" data-toggle="tab" onclick="disabled()">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#system-check-in" data-toggle="tab" onclick="enablebtn()">System Check-in</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service-and-repair" data-toggle="tab" onclick="enablebtn()">Service & Repair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#system-check-out" data-toggle="tab" onclick="enablebtn()">System Check-out</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">

        <div class="tab-pane active" id="jobs">

                <div class="portlet box purple">
                            <div class="portlet-title">
                                <h4><i class="icon-book"></i>Jobs List</h4>
                                <div class="tools">
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="remove"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portlet-body">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>JOB NO</th>
                                            <th>CILENT NAME</th>
                                            <th>JOB DATE</th>
                                            <th >DUE DATE</th>
                                            <th>COMPL DATE</th>
                                            <th>SYS. OUT DATE</th>
                                            <th>STATUS</th>
                                            <th>PRIORITY</th>
                                            <th>ALLOC TO</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody ondblclick="$('#system-check-in').toggle()">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>Mark</td>
                                            <td>Otto</td>
                                            <td class="hidden-480">makr124</td>
                                            <td><span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                        </tr>


                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

any one can tell me...
how to move from one tab to another tab by double click on row table...

here is code working but the thing is next tab is show bottom ..
i need in tab section only...
is there any wrong in my code

Comment: Always try to give fiddle for any front-end queries, if you expect answer quickly

Comment: i deleted some code now check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
    function rowDoubleClicked(e){
    if(document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
       document.selection.empty();
    } 
    else if(window.getSelection) {
         var selection = window.getSelection();
         selection.removeAllRanges();
    }
    $('#myTabs a[href="#system-check-in"]').tab('show');

}
</script>

 </head>
<body>
<div class="tabbable tabbable-custom">
    <ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href = "#jobs" data-toggle="tab" onclick="disabled()">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#system-check-in" data-toggle="tab" onclick="enablebtn()">System Check-in</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service-and-repair" data-toggle="tab" onclick="enablebtn()">Service & Repair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#system-check-out" data-toggle="tab" onclick="enablebtn()">System Check-out</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content">

    <div class="tab-pane active" id="jobs" data-tabs="tabs">

            <div class="portlet box purple">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <h4><i class="icon-book"></i>Jobs List</h4>
                    <div class="tools">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="remove"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>JOB NO</th>
                                <th>CILENT NAME</th>
                                <th>JOB DATE</th>
                                <th >DUE DATE</th>
                                <th>COMPL DATE</th>
                                <th>SYS. OUT DATE</th>
                                <th>STATUS</th>
                                <th>PRIORITY</th>
                                <th>ALLOC TO</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ondblclick="rowDoubleClicked(event);">
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td class="hidden-480">makr124</td>
                                <td><span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="system-check-in" data-tabs="tabs">
            <p>contents related to system-check-in </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this working.. i mean moving to next tab..is working....  but tab one content not hiding and  next tab content is not showing when double click on row for that what i have to do

Comment: If that worked for you then don't forget to check it as the answer to complete the thread of question ( and would help someone in future )

Comment: what i havre to do pls help me

Comment: really sorry...didn't saw you have updated you comment...I thought its working for you...wait I will look into the problem..

Comment: Ah you haven't supplied any div with the id "system-check-in"..please read the documentation of `navs` of bootstrap here..http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.3.0/docs/components.html#navs

Comment: i have mentioned div id  <div class="tab-pane" id="system-check-in">tab2</div> like this in my code

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer...this works fine for me...let me know any further queries

Comment: when we dynamically generating data table we will not mention <tr><td> like what u wrote  <tr ondblclick="rowDoubleClicked(event);"> ... in this case how to call